# Using 2 SDA and SLC for 2 different sensors

Tags: i2c

So,

Currently I am using a RTC with my Pi. It takes up the SDA and SCL pins which are  GPIO2 and GPIO3.

I now wish to add a Lux sensor.  I am using the BH1750 Light Sensor. It too needs to use the SDA and SCL GPIO pin.

The design I am using cannot use a shim or hat in addition to everything else that I am using so the only option I have is to use different pins.

I read how to 'add' additional I2C ports by adding an entry to the boot.config file. Which was this line:

```
dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,bus=2,i2c_gpio_sda=12,i2c_gpio_scl=13
```

So I am saying (hopefully) use GPIO pins 12 and 13.

But the sensor does not show up:

I tested that by 1st typing in:

```
sudo i2cdetect -1
```

Which gave me:

[image]

Then I did this:

```
sudo i2cdetect -y 3
```

Which gave me:

[image]

Comment: You need to explain how you are connecting devices and why you can't use the normal bus.

Comment: DO NOT post pictures of text post TEXT

Comment: @Milliways Sorry what does that mean? What is wrong with a screenshot? Is that not more clearer than just typing the text.?

Comment: Unless you mean type TEXT for the commands and put the result into the sreenshot only. Hapopy to do so if that is what you meant. Please confirm? Thanks

Comment: @Milliways Thanks for all your feedback. V useful. Hopefully I have addressed these issues now? I know I have accepted an answer that did not actullay solve my question but it did give the solution. But that may not be obeying the rules here. If you feel I should delete my question I will do so.  Thanks again

Comment: Your problem *seems* to be distinguishing between the physical wiring and the interconnections. You must try to get your mind wrapped around this.

Comment: I believe I have.  I understand about buses.  My question was related to the overlays not working. If I use the approach to the answer I accepted I have solved the issue. No one here has told me why my INITIAL approach which is copied from a link did not work. But never mind. BTW, your comment is constructive

Comment: `Is that not more clearer than just typing the text` ... not type text ...  copy the text and paste it into the question ... how can a picture of text be clearer than the text? ... text can be read by people with vision problems, pictures cannot

Comment: @jsotola Did you not read all my comments regarding this? I  understood the point finally and edited my question.   But fair enough point on vision problems

Comment: @Milliways No need to be so RUDE and ARROGANT by typing in uppercase. It comes across as aggressive

Comment: @jsotola Both look as clear as it each other. I always had issues with this particular forum. Bitchy..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I2C is a **bus**, and that means you can connect more than a single device to the same bus (SDA+SCL pair). IOW, you can connect your RTC ***and*** your BH1750 Light Sensor to the I2C bus on pins GPIO 2 & GPIO 3 (`I2C1`).

Since you already have `I2C1` set up for use with your RTC, all you should need to do is add the device tree overlay for the BH1750 to the file at `/boot/config.txt`. Consult the file `/boot/overlays/README` file on your RPi's local drive (or the [GitHub version here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/boot/overlays/README)) to get the proper syntax for the overlay; it should be something like this assuming you have grounded the ADDR pin on the BH1750:

```
dtoverlay=i2c-sensor,bh1750=0x23
```

You can install & use the `i2c-tools` package to verify your I2C bus is working properly before you start coding:

```
$ sudo apt update
...
$ sudo apt install i2c-tools 
...
$ i2cdetect -y 1
... which should yield something like this : 
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

The `UU` designation at addr `0x23` indicates the driver for the BH1750 has been loaded. If you don't see this, try rebooting, or use the `dtoverlay` command if you're feeling frisky :)

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your reply. But this would involve physically connecting both to the same pins.  The design I am using cannot use a shim or hat in addition to everything else that I am using so the only option I have is to use different pins.  But useful info. Thanks

Comment: @AndrewSimpson So you put the real question in a comment to an answer.  People tend to look at questions just the once.  The people who could have answered your question will probably never see this new information.

Comment: Ah. Thank you Joan, I got a lot to learn. Let me adjuts. Many thanks!

Comment: I am going to accept this answer. I have wired to wires to one GPIO end point and it works. So thank you